# I cannot make my XAML form auto re-size correctly

Tags: vb.net, xaml, autoresize, window-resize

I would like my application to rescale itself when it resizes. Currently it appears to get the correct scale, but when it changes the scale it has a bit chopped of around the side and not all controls appear. It is like a border and the font does not appear to be correct.

This application is an UWP.

i have gone on about 20-30 websites just to find the following code.

```
Public Sub resize(sender As Object, e As SizeChangedEventArgs) Handles Me.SizeChanged
    Dim myRotateTransform As New CompositeTransform()
    myRotateTransform.CenterX = 0
    myRotateTransform.CenterY = 0
    myRotateTransform.Rotation = 0
    myRotateTransform.SkewX = 0
    myRotateTransform.SkewY = 0
    myRotateTransform.TranslateX = 0
    myRotateTransform.TranslateY = 0
    Dim meS = meSize
    myRotateTransform.ScaleX = meS.Width / 1920
    myRotateTransform.ScaleY = meS.Height / 1080
    Me.RenderTransform = myRotateTransform
End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property meSize As Size
    Get
        Dim dWidth As Double = -1
        Dim dHeight As Double = -1
        Dim pnlClient As FrameworkElement = TryCast(Me.Content, FrameworkElement)
        If pnlClient IsNot Nothing Then
            dWidth = pnlClient.ActualWidth
            dHeight = pnlClient.ActualHeight
        End If
        Return New Size(dWidth, dHeight)
    End Get
End Property
```

It works better than what I had before, but now when you make the form smaller it looks like it has padding on it even though it doesn't.

Can you help me fix it?

Comment: I think you description is a little unclear. Can you please explain what you are trying to achieve? Also, is it necessary to use a Transform instead of simply resizing your window and window elements? Or perhaps even using the SizeToContent property on your Window. Explaining the purpose behind your implementation may help to get you an accurate solution.

Comment: You shouldn't need any of this if your layout is structured properly just to do standard resizing, do you have any actual xaml?